# Running flyway to migrate db to Azure SQL db: Unable to obtain connection from database

Tags: azure-sql-database, database-migration, flyway, azure-sql-server, azure-elasticpool

I have a flyway script that I run to migrate my db to Azure SQL db. Looks something like this:

```
flyway.url=jdbc:sqlserver://myazuresqlserver.database.windows.net/myazuresqldatabase;ssl=request;integratedSecurity=false; 
flyway.user=myazuresqluser
flyway.password=myazuresqlpassword
...
```

And when I run it I get the following error:

```
Unable to obtain connection from database (jdbc:sqlserver://myazuresqlserver.database.windows.net/myazuresqldatabase;ssl=request;integratedSecurity=false;) for user 'myazuresqluser': The TCP/IP connection to the host dbserver-appinfra-test-000.database.windows.net/sqldb-appinfra-smartsuitemainoperational, port 1433 has failed. Error: "myazuresqlserver.database.windows.net/myazuresqldatabase. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
```

So the thing is I already have one db that I migrated to another Azure SQL db. The script file for that one was almost idetical to the one I am using to migrate this database. I saw posts similar to mine, and, as you can see, I tried adding stuff like "`ssl=request`" to the connection string, which didn't work, and also setting setting the minimum required TLS version of the azure sql db to the lowest one.

So, because I followed the exact same steps for the other database and it the migration to Azure worked there, I looked closely into the connection strings of my azure databases. Both of the databases are on the same azure SQL server that I created, and both of them are in the same elastic pool that I created.

From my understanding the problem is that, looking at the connection strings, both of the database have this in their connection strings:

```
myazuresqlserver:1433
```

Also, important to mention - I did try to connect to this database from Azure Data Studio and SSMS. And it connects just fine

So I think they are both on the same port of the same server, that is the problem.
Could someone let me know how I could change the port of my Azure SQL database to something else in Azure? Or if it is unrelated please let me know what I can do. Help much appreciated!

Comment: Is this an Java integration or are you using the command line package?

Comment: @Barry the command line package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the line `flyway.url=jdbc:sqlserver://myazuresqlserver.database.windows.net/myazuresqldatabase`
This is what I had in my other flyway migration file (which worked perfectly) so I thought there shouldn't be any problem with this line. But I had to change it to

```
flyway.url=jdbc:sqlserver://myazuresqlserver.database.windows.net;database=myazuresqldatabase;
```

Hope this will help someone!